# react how to judge component with dom

Tags: html, reactjs, dom, events, components

```
const ButtonCom = ({ text }: any) => {
    return <Button style={{ width: 'auto', padding: '0 10px' }}>{text}</Button>;
};

const funcDom = ButtonCom({ text: '函数正常' });
const componentDom = <ButtonCom text="组件不行" />;
```

how to judge "componentDom" and "funcDom" because "componentDom" do not have html event like onClick,onMouseMove and so on

Comment: What do you mean in "judge"? Whats the differences?

Comment: lt is means how to distinguish，i expect to get the boolean return in a function

Comment: Its not clear what you asking, in any way you should never call ButtonCom() as a function unless you return a static JSX, same for you case, you should not call ButtonCom() with props as a function.